# Coq: automate repeated rewriting

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

```
Example test: forall f (n: nat), f n = n -> f (f n) = n.
Proof.
  intros f n H. repeat rewrite H. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

What would be a good way to further automate this? In particular, I would like to not have to mention the name of the hypothesis anywhere.

Comment: `repeat rewrite H.` can be replaced with `rewrite ?H.` (rewrite zero or more times) or `rewrite !H.` (rewrite one or more times).

Comment: There is also `autorewrite` tactics.

Comment: Is there a way to make `autorewrite` consider local hypotheses?

Comment: You can use this new [`strat_rewrite` tactic](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/2d6e395dead61a49ede6208bc40e16b4b8e68ce4/CHANGES#L1028): `Require Import Setoid. Hint Rewrite my_hint : my_db. <...> rewrite_strat topdown <local_term>; topdown (hints my_db).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal can be solved with some sequence of rewrites, then the [`congruence`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/tactics.html#congruence) tactic can handle it.

> The tactic `congruence`, by Pierre Corbineau, implements the standard Nelson and Oppen congruence closure algorithm, which is a decision procedure for ground equalities with uninterpreted symbols. It also include the constructor theory (see 8.5.7 and 8.5.6). If the goal is a non-quantified equality, `congruence` tries to prove it with non-quantified equalities in the context. Otherwise it tries to infer a discriminable equality from those in the context. Alternatively, `congruence` tries to prove that a hypothesis is equal to the goal or to the negation of another hypothesis.
>
> `congruence` is also able to take advantage of hypotheses stating quantified equalities, you have to provide a bound for the number of extra equalities generated that way. Please note that one of the members of the equality must contain all the quantified variables in order for `congruence` to match against it.

The above basically means that `congruence` can solve your goal if it can be solved using `rewrite` and `discriminate` tactics. But sometimes `congruence` can't help you because it does not unfold definitions for you -- in that case you'll have to help it.

```
Example test: forall f (n: nat), f n = n -> f (f n) = n.
Proof. congruence. Qed.
```